# Sticky navigation on mobile but not desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've implemented the header design based on http://codepen.io/MarcRay/pen/vmJBn

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

However I need the mobile header to be sticky instead of making the user scroll to activate it. I'm useless with javascript. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Get the size of a screen in JS like `window.screen.width` and specify it in you condition (e.g. you specify mobiles as clients with screen width < 700 px ):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (window.screen.width < 700  || $(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

**P.S.** Other conditions for finding out whether you are in a mobile can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

**UPDATE** From cited answer:

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;
```

Comment: This will only activate the sticky header on mobile after the first scroll event was fired.

Comment: Then move out the device check. If device is movlbile assume sticky class and in else block supply you code )

Comment: Can you please show the code with the device check?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a mediaquery to your css, that overrides the JS behaviour of yours:
(766px being the last screen with where the header is always visible)

<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbRaOo)</kbd>

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .main_h {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
    }

    .hero {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
}
```

**PS:** Note that I added a `margin-top` to the `.hero` block, so that it is fully visible when the user has not scrolled down yet:

Comment: This works for mobile however it also applies the sticky class to the desktop view. Ideally it would only sticky on mobile and not desktop

Comment: You won't find the one true device check to ensure that the screen is in a mobile device. We live in a world of giant phones and tiny computers. Media queries are the current standard and best practice to ensure that mobile styles land on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Seem to have solved it based on Nirazul's codepen so thank you very much!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGdWVd

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .main_h {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
  } 
  .sticky {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
  }
}

.sticky {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
}
```